# Find endpoint IP address in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I need to create a deployment descriptor "A" yaml in which I can find the endpoint IP address of a pod (that belongs to a deployment "B") . There is an option to use Downward API but I don't know if I can use it in that case.

Comment: why not use a service?

Comment: @rohatgisanat I am using service but I don't want the ClusterIP , I need the podIP.

Comment: can you explain what is the use case you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @rohatgisanat I have deployed an nginx in my cluster and I have one other microservice called "X" deployed in my cluster. In this microservice "X" in the deployment,yml I have specify the following :  - hostnames: - test.api.com ip: 10.10..10.7 . This works properly but the thing is the mentioned ip address (10.10..10.7) is the pod ip address (endpoint) of my nginx that is deployed in the same cluster. If for some reason nginx will be restarted the ip address will be changed. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to map the `test.api.com` hostname to the IP address of a specific Pod.
As **@whites11** rightly pointed out, you can use [Headless Services with selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors):

> For headless Services that define selectors, the endpoints controller creates Endpoints records in the API, and modifies the DNS configuration to return A records (IP addresses) that point directly to the Pods backing the Service.

In this case, it may be difficult to properly configure the `/etc/hosts` file inside a Pod, but it is possible to configure the Kubernetes cluster DNS to achieve this goal.

If you are using `CoreDNS` as a DNS server, you can configure `CoreDNS` to map one domain (`test.api.com`) to another domain (headless service DNS name) by adding a `rewrite` rule.

I will provide an example to illustrate how it works.

---

First, I prepared a sample `web` Pod with an associated `web` Headless Service:

```
# kubectl get pod,svc -o wide
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/web        1/1     Running   0          66m   10.32.0.2   kworker   <none>           <none>

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
service/web          ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    65m   run=web
```

We can check if the `web` headless Service returns A record (IP address) that points directly to the `web` Pod:

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup web.default.svc
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   web.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.32.0.2
```

Next, we need to configure `CoreDNS` to map `test.api.com` -> `web.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Configuration of `CoreDNS` is stored in the `coredns` `ConfigMap` in the `kube-system` namespace. You can edit it using:

```
# kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
```

Just add one `rewrite` rule, like in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        rewrite name test.api.com web.default.svc.cluster.local # mapping test.api.com to web.default.svc.cluster.local
...
```

To reload CoreDNS, we may delete `coredns` Pods (`coredns` is deployed as Deployment, so new Pods will be created)

Finally, we can check how it works:

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup test.api.com
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   test.api.com
Address: 10.32.0.2
```

As you can see, the `test.api.com` domain also returns the IP address of the `web` Pod.

For more information on the `rewrite` plugin, see the  [Coredns rewrite documentation](https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an `Headless service` (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)).

With an headless service, the service will not have an own IP address. If you specify a selector for the service, the DNS service will return the pods' IP when you query the service's name.

Quoting the documentation:

> For headless Services that define selectors, the endpoints controller
> creates Endpoints records in the API, and modifies the DNS
> configuration to return A records (IP addresses) that point directly
> to the Pods backing the Service.

In order to create an headless service, simply set the `.spec.clusterIP` to `None` and specify the selector as you would normally do with a traditional service.

Comment: thank you @whites11 .This works properly but the thing is that I am not able to use it for the purpose that I want because in the deployment "B" I want to specify the this ip address inside the /etc/hosts something like this:   
` - hostnames:

       - test.api.com 
   ip:  "service name" `                                                                                                                     and unfortunately we can not specify service name inside the /etc/hosts only IP address in applicable.

Comment: Well you will never be able to do this properly. There is little to no control over how IP addresses are assigned to pods and thus hardcoding ip addresses of pods will eventually lead to outdated IPs. My suggestion is to somehow rely on internal DNS service